# Sum of Squares and Cross Products for Hypothesis and Error for Split Plot MANOVA in R

Tags: r, sas

I'm doing the split-plot MANOVA in R by using the following data

```
Data <- read.table(tc <- textConnection("
A   Rep B   Y1  Y2  Y3  Y4  Y5
A1  1   B1  10.946  22.467  762.548 1.345   20.033
A1  1   B2  10.786  19.975  761.904 1.363   16.378
A1  1   B3  10.241  23.4    776.061 1.37    17.518
A1  1   B4  10.214  23.675  743.886 1.331   26.721
A1  1   B5  10.45   22.425  758.687 1.371   21.799
A1  1   B6  9.652   22.925  718.79  1.346   23.467
A1  1   B7  11.353  29.15   741.312 1.354   22.454
A1  1   B8  9.726   24.55   768.983 1.362   21.277
A1  1   B9  10.409  28.275  775.418 1.358   20.278
A1  1   B10 11.194  27.75   743.243 1.34    20.14
A1  1   B11 10.296  24.15   736.808 1.341   27.561
A1  1   B12 10.476  24.2    741.312 1.338   24.083
A1  1   B13 9.684   19.125  769.626 1.356   18.235
A1  1   B14 8.712   24.65   737.451 1.372   17.431
A1  1   B15 11.25   22.35   756.756 1.355   23.744
A1  1   B16 10.067  24.225  762.548 1.358   16.288
A1  2   B15 11.149  24.1    759.33  1.351   22.232
A1  2   B2  10.782  19.4    759.33  1.368   17.903
A1  2   B10 10.834  27.95   763.191 1.351   21.558
A1  2   B13 10.077  19.7    748.391 1.362   16.45
A1  2   B11 10.202  24.275  747.747 1.348   25.252
A1  2   B5  11.056  23.15   754.826 1.354   24.118
A1  2   B12 9.976   23.225  760.617 1.35    21.212
A1  2   B14 9.791   25.35   750.321 1.382   18.348
A1  2   B8  10.895  25.075  761.261 1.357   20.827
A1  2   B6  9.609   25.125  758.043 1.364   25.108
A1  2   B4  8.852   23.883  758.687 1.348   22.48
A1  2   B16 10.438  20.925  768.983 1.358   16.858
A1  2   B1  10.109  24.675  767.696 1.346   20.561
A1  2   B9  10.882  23.975  784.427 1.355   21.78
A1  2   B7  11.724  25.925  761.904 1.362   19.476
A1  2   B3  9.873   24  772.844 1.356   17.524
A1  3   B13 9.644   21.167  762.805 1.346   19.92
A1  3   B6  9.991   26.5    744.53  1.362   24.05
A1  3   B5  11.265  24.15   758.043 1.333   24.505
A1  3   B14 10.49   25.8    751.608 1.366   15.401
A1  3   B8  10.772  26.525  761.261 1.352   19.184
A1  3   B11 10.604  25.925  753.539 1.352   26.824
A1  3   B3  10.686  23.45   778.635 1.366   17.328
A1  3   B16 9.443   28.75   767.696 1.371   16.968
A1  3   B4  11.723  24.975  752.252 1.342   23.929
A1  3   B7  11.911  28.675  770.913 1.362   20.636
A1  3   B10 11.044  27.925  763.191 1.351   21.936
A1  3   B9  10.1    28.15   774.774 1.359   21.258
A1  3   B1  8.653   22.475  767.696 1.331   20.223
A1  3   B15 10.775  24.15   752.895 1.345   24.161
A1  3   B2  10.24   18.15   774.774 1.366   20.323
A1  3   B12 11.252  25.25   754.826 1.34    23.289
A2  1   B11 1.667   10.1    589.446 1.174   71.956
A2  1   B9  1.595   12.25   671.171 1.204   62.015
A2  1   B7  1.239   9.1 468.992 1.156    
A2  1   B8  0.422   11.5    573.075 1.167    
A2  1   B10 0.342   9.025   587.511 1.203    
A2  1   B13 1.423   9.575   612.612 1.153   74.968
A2  1   B6  1.166   10.025  555.984 1.201   69.652
A2  1   B3  0.98    8.325   581.081 1.162   75.744
A2  1   B2  0.582   7.425   573.075 1.108    
A2  1   B4  0.446   8.125   587.511 1.152   90
A2  1   B14 1.221   7.975   593.307 1.176   60.277
A2  1   B1  2.015   9.95    619.691 1.202   76.751
A2  1   B16 1.309   9.075   605.533 1.174   77.219
A2  1   B15 1.1 9.475   595.238 1.149   84.298
A2  1   B12 0.884   6.125   576.099 1.148   80.095
A2  1   B5  0.288   8.475   507.902 1.118    
A2  2   B6  0.74    9.325   613.899 1.271   67.744
A2  2   B8  0.508   6.8 673.101 1.223   65.377
A2  2   B3  0.238   5.35    602.96  1.15    76.194
A2  2   B1  0.925   5.45    602.96  1.2 80.177
A2  2   B14 0.475   4.575       1.136   61.903
A2  2   B16 4.518   11.35   649.935 1.187   72.118
A2  2   B2  2.607   8.25    599.742 1.162   82.612
A2  2   B7  1.664   10.7    590.09  1.172   73.57
A2  2   B13 1.584   7.625   559.845 1.157   81.399
A2  2   B9  2.039   15.575  675.675 1.254   60.811
A2  2   B15 2.648   10.1    609.395 1.164   77.74
A2  2   B11 2.277   16.5    633.204 1.205   69.425
A2  2   B5  1.442   9.15        1.146   75.663
A2  2   B12 2.073   10.775  631.274 1.175   68.576
A2  2   B10 1.644   11.45   638.996 1.191   66.842
A2  2   B4  1.312   8   574.646 1.146   79.375
A2  3   B9  3.286   16.775  721.364 1.275   61.76
A2  3   B2  1.931   7.475   599.099 1.157   82.169
A2  3   B13 1.018   6.675       1.144   81.615
A2  3   B1  2.197   11.85   627.413 1.202   82.249
A2  3   B14 0.966   9.85    611.325 1.179   58.796
A2  3   B12 1.024   7.35        1.14    82.797
A2  3   B6  1.498   11.725  637.065 1.251   66.161
A2  3   B16 1.284   9.5 579.15  1.17    73.011
A2  3   B11 1.791   10.775  589.06  1.179   69.603
A2  3   B8  1.679   13  666.666 1.223   64.473
A2  3   B15 1.845   11.1    607.464 1.16    78.837
A2  3   B5  0.98    6.325       1.132   81.264
A2  3   B7  0.831   8.2     1.162   75.246
A2  3   B4  0.873   6.625   553.825 1.122   85.433
A2  3   B3  1.439   11.3    624.195 1.196   61.882
A2  3   B10 1.506   10.825  646.074 1.196   70.917
A3  1   B16 5.183   20.575  773.487 1.333   21.848
A3  1   B6  5.538   20.45   794.079 1.347   23.38
A3  1   B8  6.527   22.325  770.27  1.332   27.505
A3  1   B1  6.076   18.75   784.427 1.346   19.53
A3  1   B14 4.2 21.325  784.427 1.364   17.889
A3  1   B10 6.816   22.225  759.33  1.314   27.247
A3  1   B9  6.629   24.025  794.079 1.357   20.466
A3  1   B5  4.053   14.45   712.998 1.278   34.904
A3  1   B2  6.288   15.5    750.321 1.342   22.114
A3  1   B11 5.62    20.325  767.696 1.323   33.483
A3  1   B13 4.377   13.025  658.301 1.242   45.57
A3  1   B12 5.59    21.075  785.07  1.34    23.19
A3  1   B15 3.83    15.025  722.007 1.288   37.806
A3  1   B7  6.676   20.275  767.696 1.329   27.785
A3  1   B3  5.051   20.75   803.088 1.364   18.018
A3  1   B4  4.691   15.1    709.781 1.284   37.364
A3  2   B1  5.786   19.475  785.07  1.348   19.692
A3  2   B16 5.433   20.55   783.14  1.35    19.014
A3  2   B4  4.784   15.25   703.346 1.263   38.752
A3  2   B5  4.937   15.7    726.512 1.299   33.649
A3  2   B13 5.503   15.95   734.877 1.318   29.355
A3  2   B8  6.365   19.875  769.626 1.325   28.599
A3  2   B2  5.198   14  738.738 1.329   25.158
A3  2   B7  7.124   23.225  775.418 1.33    25.612
A3  2   B9  5.301   21.575  784.427 1.344   24.722
A3  2   B6  5.549   22.075  791.505 1.344   26.306
A3  2   B14 4.559   20.225  784.427 1.368   19.346
A3  2   B3  5.881   18.85   797.297 1.351   24.062
A3  2   B10 5.982   21.225  754.826 1.303   28.48
A3  2   B11 6.196   21.425  766.409 1.32    34.234
A3  2   B12 6.117   21.5    769.626 1.324   26.425
A3  2   B15 5.816   15.625  724.581 1.293   34.943
A3  3   B1  6.181   19.925  789.575 1.34    20.271
A3  3   B11 6.961   20.8    776.705 1.338   31.354
A3  3   B8  6.617   23.25   780.566 1.338   26.629
A3  3   B6  6.959   26  778.635 1.344   23.185
A3  3   B5  5.608   15.475  722.651 1.298   35.883
A3  3   B14 6.548   22.625  789.575 1.374   15.987
A3  3   B4  4.59    13.975  648.005 1.228   48.702
A3  3   B2  6.684   14.1    735.521 1.329   25.888
A3  3   B7  6.774   22.35   763.835 1.325   27.918
A3  3   B16 5.773   22.15   784.427 1.344   21.004
A3  3   B12 7.172   21.925  787.001 1.332   23.976
A3  3   B9  6.584   23.675  796.653 1.349   20.609
A3  3   B13 4.622   14.875  715.572 1.301   31.807
A3  3   B3  5.921   21.55   792.792 1.36    21.521
A3  3   B10 6.278   23.625  769.626 1.315   28.586
A3  3   B15 5.07    15.65   720.077 1.29    35.372
A4  1   B7  10.174  29.15   803.732 1.374   20.431
A4  1   B5  10.025  21.75   785.07  1.348   24.449
A4  1   B1  7.727   30.675  795.366 1.34    23.269
A4  1   B8  9.9 25.2    799.227 1.357   17.634
A4  1   B12 9.7 23.783  793.436 1.348   22.657
A4  1   B15 8.771   21.575  792.792 1.355   22.612
A4  1   B16 10.124  24.35   808.88  1.354   16.704
A4  1   B10 9.621   28.875  803.732 1.359   19.26
A4  1   B4  9.763   21.875  781.853 1.344   25.39
A4  1   B2  9.639   16.775  786.357 1.355   19.489
A4  1   B3  10.835  21.675  795.366 1.353   20.44
A4  1   B6  10.996  25.2    754.826 1.341   34.872
A4  1   B14 9.913   25.9    803.732 1.373   14.841
A4  1   B11 16.508  21.6    787.644 1.349   30.582
A4  1   B13 10.981  20.975  788.288 1.364   15.359
A4  1   B9  10.94   27.5    814.028 1.374   14.328
A4  2   B2  10.606  22.025  796.01  1.359   18.222
A4  2   B15 8.086   21.5    788.288 1.354   23.742
A4  2   B7  9.288   27.717  803.088 1.366   20.544
A4  2   B16 10.224  24.875  811.454 1.356   14.521
A4  2   B6  10.429  27.725  767.052 1.337   28.561
A4  2   B1  10.916  19.1    791.505 1.344   21.068
A4  2   B9  9.913   27.25   816.602 1.371   16.655
A4  2   B8  11.46   25.825  798.584 1.359   19.354
A4  2   B10 9.175   27.575  805.662 1.375   19.988
A4  2   B11 9.41    21.125  780.566 1.328   33.694
A4  2   B4  8.524   21.575  785.07  1.353   24.372
A4  2   B12 9.947   25.6    796.653 1.348   21.886
A4  2   B5  7.93    22.3    791.505 1.361   21.973
A4  2   B13 7.879   21.7    794.079 1.365   15.912
A4  2   B14 11.022  27.875  791.505 1.368   14.528
A4  2   B3  10.699  20.425  794.079 1.352   22.81
A4  3   B10 9.203   29.1    803.088 1.358   18.451
A4  3   B7  8.261   28.875  814.028 1.369   17.177
A4  3   B3  10.8    21.45   795.366 1.359   22.341
A4  3   B13 9.883   21.85   783.14  1.36    15.446
A4  3   B11 8.182   21.3    776.705 1.327   33.511
A4  3   B16 10.23   27.1    805.019 1.35    16.389
A4  3   B14 10.419  26  801.801 1.387   15.209
A4  3   B1  10.556  20.225  794.079 1.344   21.278
A4  3   B12 10.734  25.45   798.584 1.357   20.884
A4  3   B15 10.432  20.75   792.149 1.364   21.516
A4  3   B8  10.359  24.7    796.01  1.356   19.032
A4  3   B9  11.011  25.45   819.176 1.367   16.18
A4  3   B4  12.165  21.875  796.01  1.357   22.221
A4  3   B2  10.919  16.75   790.862 1.354   19.671
A4  3   B6  10.017  27.55   769.626 1.332   32.058
A4  3   B5  10.245  22.025  787.644 1.35    23.351
A5  1   B16 2.03    20.625  755.941 1.36    18.358
A5  1   B6  2.399   21.95   760.479 1.363   17.784
A5  1   B8  4.047   22.65   780.566 1.356   17.449
A5  1   B1  3.651   22.15   794.079 1.359   15.4
A5  1   B14 3.62    21.2    785.07  1.368   14.513
A5  1   B10 4.781   24.525  794.723 1.356   20.509
A5  1   B9  3.255   23.125  814.671 1.38    13.658
A5  1   B5  0.771       714.968 1.326   41.98
A5  1   B2  2.172   19.95   792.149 1.373   14.747
A5  1   B11 3.428   23.75   787.644 1.355   22.675
A5  1   B13 1.981   20.9    769.626 1.352   19.245
A5  1   B12 1.328   26.5    790.862 1.359   18.084
A5  1   B15 2.053   23.225  745.173 1.325   27.575
A5  1   B7  2.96    21.85   784.427 1.364   17.643
A5  1   B3  3.949   19.4    800.514 1.366   13.362
A5  1   B4  2.797   22.475  750.965 1.331   26.011
A5  2   B1  4.22    19.925  801.158 1.364   15.974
A5  2   B16 1.207   22.5    790.218 1.359   15.471
A5  2   B4  3.34                 
A5  2   B5  1.286   21.6    775.418 1.353   22.037
A5  2   B13 0.992   19.725  761.261 1.353   16.896
A5  2   B8  0.862   22.2    750.992 1.36    14.992
A5  2   B2  1.076       740.405 1.325   29.78
A5  2   B7  2.156   26.45   783.783 1.365   17.274
A5  2   B9  3.567   20.875  802.445 1.374   15.411
A5  2   B6  3.911   19.05   774.774 1.348   19.857
A5  2   B14 2.916   21.25   783.783 1.369   13.759
A5  2   B3  3.133   16.125  795.366 1.369   14.838
A5  2   B10 2.27    29.15   802.445 1.365   16.55
A5  2   B11 5.476   27.175  797.297 1.371   18.261
A5  2   B12 1.669   23.325  792.792 1.349   17.488
A5  2   B15 7.583   24.3    772.844 1.349   18.701
A5  3   B1  5.304   17.5    790.218 1.354   16.79
A5  3   B11 4.444   17  773.487 1.339   23.587
A5  3   B8  5.473   19.025  779.922 1.349   17.47
A5  3   B6  5.948   19.95   766.409 1.336   28.229
A5  3   B5      13.925  662.162 1.252   52.154
A5  3   B14     21.175  747.747 1.337   23.447
A5  3   B4  3.251   16.7    714.929 1.29    37.962
A5  3   B2  4.174   15.45   765.122 1.373   14.603
A5  3   B7  7.771   23.375  725.225 1.365   17.809
A5  3   B16 4.439   22.725  803.732 1.373   12.581
A5  3   B12 5.292   25.05   797.94  1.356   16.857
A5  3   B9  6.437   20.1    799.227 1.368   16.454
A5  3   B13 4.988   16.85   759.974 1.351   19.3
A5  3   B3  0.669   19.3    788.931 1.356   20.689
A5  3   B10 0.849   26.15   787.644 1.347   22.238
A5  3   B15 0.666   21.075  763.835 1.334   28.851
A6  1   B3  8.822   23.55   799.227 1.368   20.441
A6  1   B13 9.368   22.067  806.306 1.376   18.265
A6  1   B14 6.572   23.7    809.523 1.392   14.031
A6  1   B16 7.1 23.017  787.001 1.344   21.233
A6  1   B9  9.701   26.725  803.732 1.37    17.701
A6  1   B8  10.685  30.35   810.81  1.367   14.775
A6  1   B4  11.035  24.475  798.798 1.375   16.635
A6  1   B12 8.921   27.85   799.871 1.357   19.567
A6  1   B10 9.431   31.025  807.378 1.374   15.811
A6  1   B1  8.343   20  781.209 1.339   23.81
A6  1   B5  10.72   25.75   820.463 1.381   15.697
A6  1   B15 10.487  24.3    811.454 1.379   17.006
A6  1   B6  9.197   23.5    796.653 1.356   28.012
A6  1   B2  10.977  19.25   794.079 1.375   17.683
A6  1   B7  10.571  28.567  814.671 1.379   17.013
A6  1   B11 9.843   22.4    799.227 1.354   26.885
A6  2   B13 10.439  23.1    801.801 1.375   16.915
A6  2   B3  8.449   22.475  808.88  1.375   18.681
A6  2   B11 9.457   26.9    798.584 1.361   22.328
A6  2   B12 9.983   28.367  796.653 1.362   19.106
A6  2   B4  9.692   27.433  814.671 1.378   17.106
A6  2   B1  8.706   21.4    783.783 1.359   21.951
A6  2   B10 10.243  32.15   817.889 1.372   15.932
A6  2   B8  11.87   29.775  811.454 1.373   14.88
A6  2   B9  9.954   25.825  803.517 1.377   16.093
A6  2   B7  10.43   27.9    815.958 1.376   17.634
A6  2   B2  10.937  17.675  806.306 1.373   16.022
A6  2   B6  8.6 22.55   777.348 1.342   29.022
A6  2   B15 9.09    25.3    814.028 1.383   16.605
A6  2   B5  9.564   23.575  811.454 1.383   15.611
A6  2   B16 9.275   25.75   804.375 1.362   15.699
A6  2   B14 8.185   22.8    815.315 1.39    14.105
A6  3   B7  10.497  27  815.315 1.376   16.85
A6  3   B13 9.357   21.167  795.366 1.37    15.266
A6  3   B9  8.674   25.583  813.384 1.373   16.03
A6  3   B10 9.304   31.2    815.315 1.378   15.696
A6  3   B1  8.148   19.825  797.297 1.355   20.923
A6  3   B4  10.532  25.75   811.454 1.382   15.296
A6  3   B14 6.254   23.667  806.306 1.387   13.405
A6  3   B12 7.008   25.5    794.079 1.353   20.211
A6  3   B16 8.132   24.5    801.158 1.36    17.368
A6  3   B11 10.383  24.875  806.949 1.362   21.382
A6  3   B6  8.785   24.3    783.783 1.35    23.681
A6  3   B8  11.635  28.275  807.593 1.372   14.423
A6  3   B3  8.501   20.625  804.375 1.374   21.299
A6  3   B5  9.802   26.8    821.75  1.386   14.861
A6  3   B15 10.078  25.35   822.393 1.382   16.044
A6  3   B2  10.015  17.675  806.949 1.379   15.585
A7  1   B11 9.971   26.825  796.01  1.36    20.541
A7  1   B15 9.565   28.25   813.384 1.379   15.433
A7  1   B8  9.893   33.825  832.26  1.364   15.04
A7  1   B9  7.135   29.1    810.81  1.38    16.703
A7  1   B16 7.563   33.425  815.958 1.373   17.447
A7  1   B6  6.581   27.225  777.348 1.355   21.014
A7  1   B2  9.134   22.475  806.306 1.381   15.128
A7  1   B7  9.807   29.175  810.167 1.381   18.353
A7  1   B13 8.032   21.475  799.227 1.381   18.199
A7  1   B12 7.676   30.25   801.158 1.361   17.286
A7  1   B4  8.595   26.65   810.167 1.379   16.822
A7  1   B14 8.37    25.975  809.523 1.386   14.919
A7  1   B1  6.825   23.325  801.158 1.368   16.936
A7  1   B5  9.224   26.675  814.671 1.382   15.219
A7  1   B3  7.281   23.1    817.889 1.393   15.15
A7  1   B10 9.044   35.7    815.315 1.377   16.436
A7  2   B9  9.089   29.325  815.958 1.381   14.726
A7  2   B2  8.79    22.175  802.445 1.379   16.568
A7  2   B10 10.738  33.975  825.611 1.331   16.463
A7  2   B5  9.008   28.775  809.523 1.382   15.846
A7  2   B12 9.294   31.8    805.662 1.367   15.586
A7  2   B1  6.913   22.85   804.375 1.374   16.089
A7  2   B4  8.191   29.225  811.454 1.38    16.729
A7  2   B11 8.889   25.675  792.792 1.364   20.47
A7  2   B13 9.394   24.7    794.079 1.379   18.963
A7  2   B3  8.156   30.375  812.097 1.378   18.086
A7  2   B14 7.843   26.2    808.236 1.387   16.248
A7  2   B16 7.31    26.1    818.532 1.38    14.936
A7  2   B6  6.641   30.175  812.741 1.36    20.799
A7  2   B8  10.107  31.775  803.732 1.369   16.201
A7  2   B7  9.16    22.175  811.454 1.387   17.612
A7  2   B15 8.244   28.425  807.593 1.384   15.442
A7  3   B12 9.057   28.65   811.454 1.366   18.134
A7  3   B1  6.861   23.5    812.097 1.375   17.135
A7  3   B13 8.484   24.617  798.584 1.378   17.695
A7  3   B11 8.201   26.375  798.584 1.362   20.516
A7  3   B8  8.38    34.3    814.028 1.371   14.961
A7  3   B3  6.751   22.625  822.393 1.389   17.498
A7  3   B2  9.503   22.375  798.584 1.38    16.528
A7  3   B9  7.798   27.275  800.514 1.386   16.209
A7  3   B15 9.029   28.65   810.167 1.382   16.719
A7  3   B7  8.97    30.225  802.445 1.377   17.245
A7  3   B5  10.04   28.933  814.028 1.38    16.864
A7  3   B16 6.908   28.325  809.523 1.377   14.784
A7  3   B4  9.098   27.8    814.671 1.389   15.216
A7  3   B6  6.012   29.35   777.348 1.358   23.69
A7  3   B14 7.264   28.4    803.732 1.386   16.866
A7  3   B10 7.66    37.5    810.167 1.379   16.339
A8  1   B16 4.247   27  811.454 1.371   17.469
A8  1   B2  6.722   18.225  797.297 1.373   20.396
A8  1   B7  6.945   24.317  792.149 1.354   27.105
A8  1   B1  4.804   20.95   805.662 1.352   20.438
A8  1   B6  4.613   29.05   805.019 1.36    25.11
A8  1   B13 4.577   19.45   759.33  1.35    24.746
A8  1   B4  5.943   23.55   801.801 1.367   23.586
A8  1   B3  3.989   18.65   806.306 1.371   21.225
A8  1   B9  4.229   27.3    824.967 1.382   20.241
A8  1   B10 6.54    29.525  814.028 1.367   23.41
A8  1   B11 6.021   24.3    800.514 1.342   32.493
A8  1   B5  6.104   22.825  792.792 1.352   23.37
A8  1   B12 6.922   27.875  804.375 1.352   23.875
A8  1   B15 6.754   24.275  801.801 1.372   20.248
A8  1   B8  5.455   31.2    803.088 1.345   19.463
A8  1   B14 4.517   24.725  803.088 1.379   19.739
A8  2   B3  4.529   22.675  808.88  1.367   22.658
A8  2   B13 4.746   17.675  731.016 1.324   28.432
A8  2   B7  6.877   25.9    791.505 1.351   27.525
A8  2   B6  3.261   25.85   792.149 1.35    24.247
A8  2   B16 3.92    25.85   814.028 1.37    15.893
A8  2   B8  6.081   28.25   807.593 1.367   20.304
A8  2   B9  5.918   28.15   825.611 1.38    19.622
A8  2   B2  5.317   17.975  799.227 1.373   19.205
A8  2   B11 6.528   26.375  796.01  1.345   29.784
A8  2   B15 6.217   24.325  805.662 1.376   21.344
A8  2   B4  4.487   21.567  785.07  1.352   26.007
A8  2   B5  6.087   24.25   809.523 1.374   20.456
A8  2   B10 5.994   29.763  817.245 1.368   21.037
A8  2   B14 6.135   23.95   805.662 1.385   19.042
A8  2   B12 6.528   27.133  810.81  1.362   22.466
A8  2   B1  4.76    22.85   815.315 1.368   20.528
A8  3   B13 3.455   20.25   743.886 1.341   26.73
A8  3   B1  4.942   22.1    807.593 1.365   19.639
A8  3   B10 5.776   30.925  807.593 1.368   22.756
A8  3   B5  6.545   24.275  800.514 1.377   22.103
A8  3   B9  3.878   28  816.602 1.378   22.725
A8  3   B4  4.916   24.6    801.801 1.373   21.726
A8  3   B3  5.748   21.625  815.958 1.378   20.842
A8  3   B15 7.568   24.675  803.088 1.376   21.039
A8  3   B12 6.084   27.575  803.088 1.358   22.309
A8  3   B16 4.063   26.725  795.366 1.356   23.763
A8  3   B6  3.612   29.275  788.288 1.353   28.822
A8  3   B11 5.466   26.45   798.584 1.347   32.859
A8  3   B7  5.939   26.625  797.297 1.358   27.659
A8  3   B8  5.661   30.025  811.454 1.368   20.423
A8  3   B14 2.533   23.15   799.227 1.377   19.143
A8  3   B2  5.301   16.95   784.427 1.369   22.939
A9  1   B8  8.908   28.175  799.871 1.368   12.955
A9  1   B4  8.273   24.35   802.445 1.373   13.235
A9  1   B1  7.472   20.8    797.297 1.369   14.353
A9  1   B5  8.808   23.475  812.741 1.378   12.292
A9  1   B14 8.067   24.625  809.523 1.389   13.665
A9  1   B15 8.995   26.225  804.375 1.377   13.469
A9  1   B2  6.206   19.175  799.871 1.377   14.69
A9  1   B7  9.778   27.6    801.801 1.371   16.124
A9  1   B13 8.18    25.3    785.714 1.368   18.33
A9  1   B3  7.936   22.975  810.167 1.386   11.341
A9  1   B16 8.787   25.45   823.037 1.381   11.62
A9  1   B11 8.071   24.25   790.218 1.361   15.167
A9  1   B6  7.473   25.6    795.366 1.359   16.692
A9  1   B9  8.79    26.375  823.68  1.387   11.944
A9  1   B12 7.895   26.025  801.158 1.368   14.529
A9  1   B10 9.099   31.85   806.306 1.375   12.969
A9  2   B12 8.991   29.575  816.602 1.371   13.701
A9  2   B4  8.844   26.5    802.445 1.381   12.056
A9  2   B9  8.278   26.725  824.967 1.385   14.12
A9  2   B8  8.527   28.925  808.88  1.374   13.366
A9  2   B5  8.311   26.95   805.019 1.383   14.069
A9  2   B6  6.499   24.625  790.862 1.358   17.618
A9  2   B2  9.412   20.475  796.653 1.376   13.741
A9  2   B16 8.009   26.375  817.245 1.382   11.936
A9  2   B15 10.036  27.15   805.019 1.38    13.556
A9  2   B10 9.479   33.75   821.75  1.386   12.528
A9  2   B14 6.617   26.1    805.662 1.393   13.299
A9  2   B3  7.67    22.35   821.106 1.397   11.727
A9  2   B11 9.042   24.65   797.94  1.363   17.142
A9  2   B1  8.015   22.3    814.671 1.381   13.444
A9  2   B7  7.75    29.7    799.227 1.374   16.425
A9  2   B13 8.168   21.25   790.862 1.377   16.372
A9  3   B1  6.881   21.1    790.862 1.368   14.115
A9  3   B11 9.169   24.825  797.94  1.358   16.476
A9  3   B4  9.129   26.8    802.445 1.381   13.853
A9  3   B14 7.555   24.25   800.514 1.387   14.93
A9  3   B16 8.377   26.275  801.801 1.387   11.885
A9  3   B7  7.36    27.3    796.653 1.382   11.223
A9  3   B5  10.215  28.25   808.88  1.374   17.517
A9  3   B12 9.753   25.75   814.028 1.379   14.708
A9  3   B2  7.671   25.475  797.94  1.37    15.711
A9  3   B8  8.549   21.15   800.514 1.378   15.154
A9  3   B6  8.801   28.775  797.94  1.365   14.123
A9  3   B10 5.741   25.625  791.505 1.349   18.78
A9  3   B3  9.379   31.2    814.028 1.381   13.838
A9  3   B9  8.652   23.575  816.602 1.387   12.983
A9  3   B13 7.843   22.2    780.566 1.374   18.146
A9  3   B15 9.432   24.75   804.375 1.38    15.123
A10 1   B10 11.286  28.075  819.819 1.354   14.646
A10 1   B1  9.574   18.475  792.792 1.37    17.585
A10 1   B12 10.99   22.25   788.288 1.36    20.025
A10 1   B8  10.909  23.925  797.297 1.369   16.103
A10 1   B15 11.221  24.833  805.662 1.384   15.419
A10 1   B16 9.432   23.575  802.445 1.374   13.821
A10 1   B14 9.216   21.075  790.862 1.39    14.995    
A10 1   B7  11.493  26.625  815.958 1.386   16.563
A10 1   B6  8.5 18.65   761.261 1.334   32.261
A10 1   B5  12.232  21.9    815.958 1.386   15.209
A10 1   B3  11.139  19.75   805.662 1.386   16.083
A10 1   B13 11.046  21.15   794.723 1.387   14.934
A10 1   B4  11.4    23.525  805.019 1.391   14.507
A10 1   B9  9.462   22.5    804.375 1.376   15.48
A10 1   B2  11.723  16.075  797.297 1.38    16.237
A10 1   B11 9.953   22.35   791.505 1.359   23.063
A10 2   B2  11.614  16.317  793.436 1.381   14.826
A10 2   B11 9.543   20.025  786.357 1.347   28.834
A10 2   B14 10.173  20.925  803.732 1.398   14.818
A10 2   B16 10.031  21.9    801.801 1.377   13.178
A10 2   B1  9.276   17.6    788.931 1.364   19.5
A10 2   B3  9.993   18.75   794.723 1.384   17.542
A10 2   B9  9.893   22.475  798.584 1.376   15.575
A10 2   B8  11.701  26.05   803.088 1.379   14.768
A10 2   B13 10.657  19.725  794.723 1.39    15.132
A10 2   B7  11.521  25.5    806.949 1.388   15.757
A10 2   B5  11.492  23.1    805.662 1.391   14.931
A10 2   B6  8.728   19.55   768.983 1.349   27.698
A10 2   B15 10.747  23.85   801.158 1.387   15.78
A10 2   B10 10.163  28.5    815.315 1.385   15.52
A10 2   B4  11.379  23.175  809.523 1.39    14.324
A10 2   B12 10.276  21.317  791.505 1.355   21.603
A10 3   B6  8.973   19.475  772.844 1.344   27.594
A10 3   B13 10.731  18.55   793.436 1.388   14.397
A10 3   B10 10.946  26.667  808.236 1.388   14.519
A10 3   B9  9.23    24.175  808.236 1.38    14.59
A10 3   B8  10.987  25.125  799.227 1.375   15.066
A10 3   B7  11.173  25.625  807.593 1.389   15.947
A10 3   B14 8.376   21.725  806.306 1.397   14.206
A10 3   B16 9.127   21.925  803.732 1.373   14.4
A10 3   B15 12.365  23.125  803.732 1.388   15.078
A10 3   B5  11.926  22.475  806.306 1.39    14.644
A10 3   B3  9.65    18.7    794.079 1.384   17.816
A10 3   B12 10.412  23.05   778.635 1.358   22.357
A10 3   B4  12.465  24.125  809.523 1.391   15.282
A10 3   B11 9.918   21.05   779.279 1.351   26.552
A10 3   B1  8.996   17.925  783.783 1.368   18.58
A10 3   B2  10.812  16.575  794.079 1.389   13.945
A11 1   B14 7.758   26.875  797.94  1.388   12.362
A11 1   B15 8.897   27.7    800.514 1.367   16.409
A11 1   B9  8.85    23.8    798.584 1.374   16.224
A11 1   B12 9.975   26.075  785.07  1.36    20.065
A11 1   B16 9.259   24.35   797.94  1.372   14.972
A11 1   B4  9.206   27.275  802.445 1.373   15.97
A11 1   B6  7.813   22.625  785.714 1.348   25.304
A11 1   B11 8.249   19.15   797.94  1.352   23.845
A11 1   B3  9.254   21.175  812.097 1.383   41.784
A11 1   B1  9.609   25.675  799.871 1.377   16.683
A11 1   B10 10.368  29.75   815.315 1.378   17.591
A11 1   B5  10.46   25.3    801.158 1.38    66.391
A11 1   B8  10.876  27.15   802.445 1.37    16.227
A11 1   B7  4.247   27.925  788.288 1.359   16.951
A11 1   B2  10.425  17.95   783.14  1.382   14.525
A11 1   B13 9.749   23.075  785.714 1.383   17.901
A11 2   B3  9.119   18.35   805.662 1.388   14.69
A11 2   B6  8.499   26.125  772.2   1.353   23.519
A11 2   B12 10.243  26.05   793.436 1.363   20.628
A11 2   B7  10.481  26.925  802.445 1.382   17.585
A11 2   B10 11.13   30.25   815.958 1.386   16.183
A11 2   B4  11.089  25.125  805.662 1.383   16.403
A11 2   B2  9.514   18.55   793.436 1.378   17.209
A11 2   B8  10.492  25.425  800.514 1.37    16.851
A11 2   B15 8.33    29.5    797.94  1.374   16.764
A11 2   B13 9.616   21.95   787.644 1.383   17.671
A11 2   B9  8.824   23.825  800.514 1.376   15.565
A11 2   B11 8.563   23.175  789.575 1.357   24.682
A11 2   B14 9.632   23.775  803.088 1.395   13.853
A11 2   B5  8.594   24.125  812.741 1.386   15.241
A11 2   B1  10.978  20.975  805.662 1.376   16.638
A11 2   B16 8.955   23.425  801.158 1.385   15.373
A11 3   B16 9.401   23.8    803.732 1.38    15.236
A11 3   B1  9.064   20.375  801.801 1.379   16.128
A11 3   B3  8.823   19.475  806.306 1.387   17.477
A11 3   B10 9.3 29.667  811.454 1.383   15.748
A11 3   B14 7.616   24.1    798.584 1.394   13.213
A11 3   B13 10.5    21.833  794.079 1.384   16.934
A11 3   B12 10.626  26.525  792.149 1.369   18.901
A11 3   B2  10.319  18.1    793.436 1.385   15.925
A11 3   B11 10.434  20.8    783.783 1.353   25.08
A11 3   B15 8.286   30.467  794.723 1.372   18.128
A11 3   B6  10.77   26.675  797.297 1.365   20.25
A11 3   B8  10.879  27.375  794.079 1.374   16.859
A11 3   B7  10.961  24.55   803.732 1.387   17.66
A11 3   B4  9.187   25.575  803.732 1.383   16.772
A11 3   B9  9.333   23.975  797.297 1.378   15.092
A11 3   B5  9.471   25.525  808.88  1.38    18.376
A12 1   B13 5.677   26.45   777.992 1.349   14.333
A12 1   B4  1.286   27.775  787.001 1.356   14.091
A12 1   B10 6.479   32.9    812.097 1.371   11.569
A12 1   B3  8.146   20.9    824.967 1.387   12.077
A12 1   B14 8.205   25.525  801.158 1.38    13.808
A12 1   B5  7.675   25.325  808.88  1.384   12.905
A12 1   B1  8.731   21.425  795.366 1.369   13.229
A12 1   B7  9.355   27.65   812.741 1.381   13.418
A12 1   B9  9.453   25.25   824.967 1.388   11.146
A12 1   B16 0.978   23.35   822.393 1.38    10.709
A12 1   B11 7.062   23.55   802.445 1.358   15.353
A12 1   B15 7.529   26.9    799.227 1.372   12.867
A12 1   B2  9.643   20.575  796.653 1.377   14.282
A12 1   B6  7.643   22.925  793.436 1.353   17.352
A12 1   B8  9.544   29.125  805.019 1.37    12.081
A12 1   B12 7.62    29.275  799.871 1.36    13.22
A12 2   B8  8.95    26.625  806.306 1.369   12.867
A12 2   B2  9.255   18.7    799.227 1.381   12.721
A12 2   B7  9.873   25.75   814.671 1.384   13.943
A12 2   B14 5.188   25.4    799.227 1.369   18.655
A12 2   B9  7.27    25.8    828.828 1.39    10.801
A12 2   B4  5.203   22.225  787.644 1.356   15.177
A12 2   B1  4.691   21.15   810.167 1.373   11.514
A12 2   B3  7.677   20.775  815.958 1.397   10.753
A12 2   B16 7.875   24  823.68  1.384   12.272
A12 2   B5  8.341   25.525  810.167 1.382   12.059
A12 2   B6  7.241   22.1    775.418 1.355   16.251
A12 2   B11 8.46    23.375  803.088 1.362   14.43
A12 2   B10 8.193   34.375  813.384 1.377   13.667
A12 2   B15 8.272   26.95   810.167 1.382   13.194
A12 2   B13 7.107   25.5    781.853 1.359   14.81
A12 2   B12 5.24    27.35   808.236 1.369   12.293
A12 3   B10 7.87    31.575  811.454 1.363   13.712
A12 3   B7  5.632   25.875  806.949 1.382   13.734
A12 3   B1  5.316   19.85   816.602 1.386   12.005
A12 3   B2  6.548   20.8    788.931 1.373   12.9
A12 3   B5  7.093   23.825  802.445 1.383   11.034
A12 3   B11 8.385   24.2    798.584 1.36    16.748
A12 3   B13 8.394   26.15   796.653 1.371   14.601
A12 3   B16 7.584   24.325  823.68  1.388   11.101
A12 3   B15 8.206   27  798.584 1.378   12.704
A12 3   B14 4.895   28.65   788.288 1.371   16.782
A12 3   B12 8.745   28.825  808.236 1.368   12.503
A12 3   B3  6.562   20.05   823.037 1.396   11.316
A12 3   B8  9.485   30.475  796.653 1.368   13.013
A12 3   B6  6.91    22.817  794.723 1.35    18.594
A12 3   B4  3.957   24.875  770.27  1.347   18.442
A12 3   B9  8.452   25.975  825.611 1.393   11.019"), header = TRUE, fill = TRUE); close(tc)
```

and the following R Code

```
Fit <- manova(formula = cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5) ~ A + Rep:A + B + A: B, data = Data)
summary.aov(Fit)
summary(Fit, test="Wilks")
summary.manova(Fit)
```

Up to this point everything is okay. Now I want to get the Sum of Squares and Cross Products for Hypothesis (for A, Rep(A), B, AB) and Error by using the following code

```
library(car)
MANOVA <- Manova(mod = Fit, type = "II")
```

and getting the following error message:

```
Error in solve.default(wcrossprod(model.matrix(mod), w = wts)) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular
```

I could not understand why I am getting this error message. Is there any other way to get these SSCPs? When I did the same analysis in SAS everything is fine. The SAS code is

```
PROC GLM DATA = Data;
CLASS A Rep B;
MODEL Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 = A Rep(A) B A*B;
MANOVA H =_all_ /PRINTE PRINTH;
RUN;
```

But I'd like to do this in R. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, when you get the message "System is singular" from some LAPACK routine, that means you can decompose the matrix in certain ways. You're probably running into an issue that you can't do the decomposition necessary (whatever it may be), so that's why you get your error. This is more of a general comment, since I've never used `R`.

Comment: I would add that errors referring to singular matrices often indicate that you are asking a statistical method to estimate something that you don't have (good) enough data to estimate. But you haven't provided enough information about your actual data for anyone to be able to comment on this.

Comment: I was able to get everything with SAS but R gave me this error.

Comment: @MYaseen208  - Unless you've gone through the source code line by line in both SAS and R to verify that the *exact* same calculations are being done in each case, saying "it worked in SAS" doesn't provide us with any useful information. Until you provide code *and* data that reproduces the error, it's unlikely anyone can help much.

Comment: @joran - I've added the data as well as SAS code. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 - As I suspected, a glance at your data reveals that there are no complete cases for A2:B5 and removing the interaction term A:B allows `Manova` to run w/out error. I've never used SAS and am not an expert on manova models so YMMV, but my guess is that your SAS code is either not doing exactly what your R code is, or it's 'hiding' the singularity issue for you somehow. Sorry, that's the best I can offer - perhaps a SAS/manova expert will swing by...

Comment: @Joran - Thanks a lot for all your help. I hope someone help me figure out this problem. Anyhow thanks again for spare your time and energy. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the SAS docs: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect038.htm

"for an analysis with the MANOVA or REPEATED statement, or with the MANOVA option in the PROC GLM statement, PROC GLM uses an observation if values are nonmissing for all dependent variables and all the variables used in independent effects."

To check, see if R produces the same value as SAS does if you restrict it to complete cases.

e.g.

```
Fit <- manova(formula = cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5) ~ A + Rep:A + B + A: B, 
              data = Data[complete.cases(Data),])
summary.aov(Fit)
summary(Fit, test="Wilks")
summary.manova(Fit)
```

The results I get for this are:

```
> Fit <- manova(formula = cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5) ~ A + Rep:A + B + A: B, 
+               data = Data[complete.cases(Data),])
> summary.aov(Fit)
 Response Y1 :
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
A            11 3976.4  361.49 302.8417 < 2.2e-16 ***
B            15  122.1    8.14   6.8188 5.124e-13 ***
A:Rep        12   22.2    1.85   1.5507  0.104296    
A:B         164  283.3    1.73   1.4470  0.002253 ** 
Residuals   357  426.1    1.19                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Response Y2 :
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value  Pr(>F)    
A            11 9221.1  838.28 297.6565 < 2e-16 ***
B            15 3260.7  217.38  77.1867 < 2e-16 ***
A:Rep        12   76.8    6.40   2.2711 0.00874 ** 
A:B         164 1482.6    9.04   3.2100 < 2e-16 ***
Residuals   357 1005.4    2.82                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Response Y3 :
             Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq   F value    Pr(>F)    
A            11 1248016  113456 1098.0101 < 2.2e-16 ***
B            15   53776    3585   34.6960 < 2.2e-16 ***
A:Rep        12    3781     315    3.0491 0.0004171 ***
A:B         164   96762     590    5.7101 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals   357   36888     103                        
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Response Y4 :
             Df  Sum Sq  Mean Sq   F value    Pr(>F)    
A            11 1.21607 0.110552 1482.0020 < 2.2e-16 ***
B            15 0.03765 0.002510   33.6438 < 2.2e-16 ***
A:Rep        12 0.00312 0.000260    3.4806 7.067e-05 ***
A:B         164 0.09905 0.000604    8.0961 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals   357 0.02663 0.000075                        
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Response Y5 :
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq   F value  Pr(>F)    
A            11 107541  9776.5 1077.0236 < 2e-16 ***
B            15   3503   233.5   25.7242 < 2e-16 ***
A:Rep        12    305    25.4    2.7966 0.00115 ** 
A:B         164   6581    40.1    4.4209 < 2e-16 ***
Residuals   357   3241     9.1                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> summary(Fit, test="Wilks")
           Df   Wilks approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
A          11 0.00022  153.064     55 1637.5 < 2.2e-16 ***
B          15 0.02663   25.580     75 1695.0 < 2.2e-16 ***
A:Rep      12 0.69568    2.225     60 1656.7  3.73e-07 ***
A:B       164 0.01175    3.093    820 1770.2 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals 357                                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> summary.manova(Fit)
           Df Pillai approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
A          11 3.4175   70.086     55   1785 < 2.2e-16 ***
B          15 2.2866   20.056     75   1785 < 2.2e-16 ***
A:Rep      12 0.3457    2.210     60   1785  4.49e-07 ***
A:B       164 2.8037    2.779    820   1785 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals 357                                            
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```